# Laravel - passsing variables to controller

Tags: php, laravel, view, controller, checksum

I am passing 2 random numbers from controller to view with form:

```
public function request()
{       
    $number1 = rand(10,20);
    $number2 = rand(0,10);
    return View::make('request', ['num1' => $number1, 'num2' => $number2]);
}
```

These 2 numbers are displayed in form:

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'MyController@verifyRequest', 'class'=>'bg-grey width')) }}
   {{ Form::label('Check sum: ') }}
   {{ Form::label($num1. ' + '. $num2. ' = ') }}
   {{ Form::text('checksum') }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Now how can I pass those two variables into controller method 'verifyRequest' to check sum of the numbers?

```
public function verifyRequest()
{   
    $sum = ???
```

Comment: What if the purpose of doing it?

Comment: It's for security reason. Or am I missing something?

Comment: you sure are. This idea is not secure from top to very bottom.

Comment: what should I do then

Comment: you should start with explaining the original task. We now only see the weird attempt that doesn't tell anything about aim.

Comment: I don't know how it exactly work, but sometimes are in forms two random number, and user must type correct sum of the numbers in order to avoid sending automated spam messages.

Comment: Check for "CAPTCHA", and "reCAPTCHA" in particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either put those data into session (what might be better solution) or add hidden fields into form:

```
{{ Form::hidden('num1', $num1) }}
{{ Form::hidden('num2', $num2) }}
```

and now in your controller you can use:

```
$sum = Input::get('num1') + Input::get('num2');
```

Comment: @Tomas Turan: are you aware that you cannot trust user input?

Comment: @zerkms is it somehow related to hidden inputs?

Comment: @Tomas Turan: yep. User inputs are sent by client so can be forged

Comment: @TomasTuran The problem with using hidden fields is that user can put them anything he want, so he can always fill the form with `1+1=2` and it will be always true (in controller you cannot track it if you are not using sessions)

Comment: but how can user input data in field that is hidden?

Comment: @TomasTuran He can for example use software for that or he can use for example FireBug plugin in Firefox and he can change value (and names) of anything he want in page source

Answer (score 1):

You can insert `num1` and `num2` sum result at `session` and check in `verifyRequest` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
  {{ Form::open(array('action' => 'MyController@verifyRequest', 'class'=>'bg-grey width')) }}
   {{ Form::label('Check sum: ') }}
   {{ Form::label($num1. ' + '. $num2. ' = ') }}
   {{ Form::text('checksum') }}
   {{ Form::hidden('num1', $num1) }}
   {{ Form::hidden('num2', $num2) }}
   {{Form::submit('Click Me!');}}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

in controller

```
 public function verifyRequest()
 {   
    $num1 = $_POST['num1'];
    $num2 = $_POST['num2']
    $checksum = $_POST['checksum']
    //Do whatever you want
 }
```